# Event Handler Not Firing in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am struggling with events.  I have a user control that I want to return the ID field from when the user double clicks.  Here is my code from the user control:

```
// inside the user control class:
public event EventHandler<SelectedItemEventArgs> ItemHasBeenSelected;

public class SelectedItemEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int SelectedChoice { get; set; }
}

private void DataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = ItemHasBeenSelected;
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex < DataGridView.RowCount)
    {
        // 6 == id column
        int choice = (int)DataGridView[6, First ? 0 : e.RowIndex].Value;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs { SelectedChoice = hoice });
    }
}
```

Inside the calling program:

```
public Main
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
    uc.ItemHasBeenSelected += uc_ItemHasBeenSelected;
}

private void uc_ItemHasBeenSelected(object sender, FindControl.SelectedItemEventArgs e)
{
    var value = e.SelectedChoice;
    currentVal = value;
}
```

I keep getting that my event handler (var handler) = null.  I know I must be missing something but it's been so many hours and I just can't find it.  Please help if you can.

Comment: Does the DoubleClick event handler fire?

Comment: Yes it does.  It goes into DoubleClick and after the line  var handler = ItemHasBeenSelected,  handler is null

Comment: _"after the line var handler = ItemHasBeenSelected, handler is null"_ -- then nothing has been subscribed to that event. Based on the incomplete code example you've provided, the most likely reason is that the `uc` object you use when you subscribe to the event is a different control object than the one that raises the event. But that's only a guess; without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create an event delegate:

```
public delegate void ItemHasBeenSelected (object sender, SelectedItemEventArgs e);
```

Instantiate the event delegate:

```
public event ItemHasBeenSelected SelectedItem;
```

When you want to raise the event:

```
this.SelectedItem(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs { SelectedChoice = choice })
```

After you have this set up, you can bind the event to the event handlers:

```
this.SelectedItem += main.uc_ItemHasBeenSelected;
```

If you are defining the delegate in the form, which is not where you want the event handler to be, you need to pass in a `this` value into the form's constructor and store that in a variable within the form. Reference that variable when assigning event handlers.

**OR**

Define the delegate from within the control, and reference that from within the main program when assigning a handler to the event.

```
Control.SelectedItem += this.uc_ItemHasBeenSelected;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment off of Nick's answer, Missy has asked me to post the best practice way of raising events.

I've simplified your code to illustrate:

```
public event EventHandler<SelectedItemEventArgs> ItemHasBeenSelected;

public class SelectedItemEventArgs : EventArgs { }

private void OnItemHasBeenSelected()
{
    var handler = this.ItemHasBeenSelected;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs());
    }
}
```

The key thing to note here is the assignment `var handler = this.ItemHasBeenSelected;`. This makes a copy of the delegate and hence the attached handlers and this means that **if anything happens to `this.ItemHasBeenSelected` it won't affect `handler`**.

Compare with the following:

```
private void OnItemHasBeenSelected()
{
    if (this.ItemHasBeenSelected != null)
    {
        this.ItemHasBeenSelected(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs());
    }
}
```

In this case there is a bug in that after the check for `this.ItemHasBeenSelected != null`, but before `this.ItemHasBeenSelected(this, new SelectedItemEventArgs());` is called, another thread (or in more complicated situations even asynchronous code) can remove the handlers so that the subsequent call will fail as the delegate will now be `null`.

By using the `var handler = this.ItemHasBeenSelected;` assignment you avoid this situation.

Comment: I've never seen a situation where another thread removed a handler. If this is such a prevalent problem, why does Visual Studio skip this step when creating events & handlers for situations like a DoubleClick?

Comment: @Nick - Are you talking about when Visual Studio creates normal event handlers for controls?

Comment: basically, yes. I don't understand why this extra step is so necessary. I've used my own event handlers with my own EventArgs, currently using it in some large, relatively complicated projects & haven't had this problem. It seems like an unnecessary extra step to me.

Comment: @Nick - When Visual Studio creates that code it's creating the handlers, not the code that raises the events. Those two different sets of code. If you decompile the winforms code you'll see the event raising code looks like `EventHandler eh = Events[EventSize] as EventHandler; if (eh != null) { eh(this,e); }`.

Comment: that's interesting

Comment: @Nick - Which bit?

Comment: Super appreciate.  Thank you!